# how to place logo center in my navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website 
see this http://surginc.com?
the logo [1]: http://surginc.com/_includes/img/logo.png "Logo"
is not going to Center in the navbar. please see this and help me to to center this in navbar ?
I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: add padding-left: 15%; to the image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the code for the logo:

```
<img style="margin:0 40%;margin-top:-55px;" src="Industrial%20Supplies%20%7C%20Textiles%20%7C%20Surg%20Inc_files/logo.png" alt="surg logo">
```

This makes it fixed to the `center` with any screen resolution!

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS class `.brand hidden-xs visible-lg visible-md visible-sm` to `width: 245px; margin: 0 auto;`

```
<a class="brand hidden-xs visible-lg visible-md visible-sm" href="http://surginc.com/index.php/" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100px; float: none;">
```

to

```
<a class="brand hidden-xs visible-lg visible-md visible-sm" href="http://surginc.com/index.php/" style="  width: 245px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Here `245px` is a width of the original image

Answer (score 0):

First add this to navigation container: `.navbar-collapse{ position:relative; }` 
Then for the logo: `.brand{ position:absolute; left:50%; top:3px; margin-left:-122px; width:245px; }` and remove the inline styles from the logo image, so it wont overwrite any future modification added in the css file